# From tree list to a matrix in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, vector, tree

Apologies, if the question is too basic. What would be an effective approach/idea (in **R**) to convert

```
list(c(1), c(1,2), c(1,2,3), c(1,2,3,4))
```

to square matrix form

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    1    2   NA   NA
[3,]    1    2    3   NA
[4,]    1    2    3    4
```

I suppose there is some quick dynamic way to append just the right number of `NA` values and then convert to a matrix.

Naturally, the size of the (square) matrix can change).

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: See this answer except use NAs in place of the zeros: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703940/tree-list-to-reverse-lower-triangular-matrix-in-r/33704844#33704844

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
## create the list
x <- Map(":", 1, 1:4)

ml <- max(lengths(x))
do.call(rbind, lapply(x, "length<-", ml))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]    1    2   NA   NA
# [3,]    1    2    3   NA
# [4,]    1    2    3    4
```

Or you could do

```
library(data.table)
as.matrix(unname(rbindlist(lapply(x, as.data.frame.list), fill = TRUE)))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]    1    2   NA   NA
# [3,]    1    2    3   NA
# [4,]    1    2    3    4
```

And one more for good measure ... Fore!

```
m <- stringi::stri_list2matrix(x, byrow = TRUE)
mode(m) <- "numeric"
m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]    1    2   NA   NA
# [3,]    1    2    3   NA
# [4,]    1    2    3    4
```