# Tree list to reverse-lower triangular matrix in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, data-structures, tree

How would I go about converting

```
m = list(1,2:3,4:6,7:10)
```

to

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0   10
[2,]    0    0    6    9
[3,]    0    3    5    8
[4,]    1    2    4    7
```

An idea or some guidance are appreciated! Thank you for your patience, in case the question is too naive or requires additional information (I'll gladly provide).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** Below the `lapply` appends `n` zeros to each component of `m` and the `sapply` takes the first `n` elements of each component of `m` reshaping the result into a matrix.  Finally we reverse the order of the rows of the resulting matrix. This works even if `m` does not define a triangular matrix:

```
n <- length(m)
sapply(lapply(m, c, numeric(n)), head, n)[n:1, ]
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0   10
[2,]    0    0    6    9
[3,]    0    3    5    8
[4,]    1    2    4    7
```

If `n` can be zero then use `rev(seq_len(n))` in place of `n:1` .

**2)** A straight forward `sapply` also works.  It prepends each reversed component of `m` with the appropriate number of zeros and reshapes into a matrix:

```
sapply(m, function(v) c(numeric(n - length(v)), rev(v)))
```

Answer (score 7):

Ill chuck a base R method forward

```
# Create matrix with dimensions defined by the length of your list 
mat <- matrix(0, length(m), length(m)) 
# Fill in desired order
mat[upper.tri(mat, TRUE)] <- unlist(m)
# Order rows 
mat[length(m):1, ]
```

Comment: Because your answer is 100 times better. Numeric to character back to numeric is not really the way things should be done

Comment: Yes, perhaps, but i do think its useful introducing lesser known functions that hide away in packages (as otherwise id never get to know them!)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option to consider. This uses `lengths` to figure out how long the longest vector is, and then uses `vapply`, which would automatically simplify to a matrix (like `sapply`, but faster).

```
len <- max(lengths(m))           ## What's the longest vector in m?
vapply(m, function(x) {
  length(x) <- len               ## Make all vectors the same length
  rev(replace(x, is.na(x), 0))   ## Replace NA with 0 and reverse
}, numeric(len))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    0    0   10
# [2,]    0    0    6    9
# [3,]    0    3    5    8
# [4,]    1    2    4    7
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sparse matrices (from the `Matrix` package), these will also work:

```
> N <- lengths(m)
> sparseMatrix(i=1+length(m)-sequence(N), j=rep.int(N,N), x=unlist(m))
4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

[1,] . . . 10
[2,] . . 6  9
[3,] . 3 5  8
[4,] 1 2 4  7
```

This is almost the same as the idiom for upper triangular matrices:

```
> sparseMatrix(i=sequence(N), j=rep.int(N,N), x=unlist(m))
4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

[1,] 1 2 4  7
[2,] . 3 5  8
[3,] . . 6  9
[4,] . . . 10
```